# Wordpress Redirect wp-admin to wp-admin/wp-login.php

Tags: php, database, wordpress

Im using Local by Flywheel for test a WP site, I import a DB and change the URL with the Local URL.

But, when im try to my admin, the site redirect..

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.local%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

I dont know why this happen, ill try everything, for example, add the URL to wp-config.php

define('WP_HOME','example.local');
define('WP_SITEURL','example.local');

also clean my cookies, try another browser, but still having that problem.

Any idea how tho fixed?

Answer (score 0):

As i see - it tries to find wp-login.php under /wp-admin/example.com/, 
not /wp-admin/.
example.com/wp-admin/**example.com**/wp-login.php

Check .htaccess file. 
Probably some routing issues.
Maybe regenerate it.

Answer (score 0):

Check permalink inside the wp admin cms. Change permalink to 'post name' to change 'plain' and then save. Now try (or) check .htaccess file us well.